# Добавление свое шрифта в проект nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-cli

Не подключается шрифт добавленный с помощью @font-face в проект nuxt.js

````
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Красиво , однако , в лесу!</p>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: Pompadur; 
  src: url(/static/fonts/pompadur.ttf); 
}
P {
  font-family: Pompadur;
  font-size:50px;
}
</style>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ссылка на документацию: [Статические файлы - NuxtJS](https://ru.nuxtjs.org/guide/static/)

---

У `Nuxt.js` есть специальный каталог для статических файлов под названием `static`.

Если вы не хотите использовать `Webpacked Assets` из папки `assets`, то можно создать и использовать папку `'static'` в корневом каталоге проекта.

`Nuxt.js` автоматически сделает доступными эти файлы через `/`.

Эта опция полезна для таких файлов, как `'robots.txt'` или `'sitemap.xml'`.

В коде проекта эти файлы будут доступны также через `/`:

```
<!-- Статическое изображение из папки `static`-->
<img src="/my-image.png"/>

<!-- Статическое изображение через Webpack из папки `assets`-->
<img src="/assets/my-image-2.png"/>
```

Comment: Уже использую эту папку , посмотрите в коде   src: url(/static/fonts/pompadur.ttf);

Comment: @panelka2 , вы внимательно прочитайте ответ то, для статик файлов уже установлена директория в `/` , а для ассетов `/assets/` . Вы должны использовать `src: url(/fonts/pompadur.ttf);`

Comment: Прощу прощения , все работает , спасибо!